# Fail to replicate a local IndexedDB to a remote CouchDB using PouchDB

Tags: google-chrome, ionic-framework, couchdb, pouchdb

I'm using PouchDB 7.0.0 in an Ionic project (Ionic 4.0.5).

Within a provider, I define both a local and a remote database:

```js
@Injectable()
export class DatabaseProvider {

  constructor() {
    this.db = new PouchDB("mydb");
    this.remote = new PouchDB("http://<my_server_running_couchdb>/<remote_db_name>")

  }
```

The local database lives in the Chrome browser as an IndexedDB instance. However, the problem also occurs in Firefox so it does not look like the browser is the guy to blame.

The remote database is initially empty and runs on CouchDB 2.1.2. It has already been created on my server with no admin or member set up, so it should be public and allow non-authenticated requests. By the way, CORS are enabled as well.

In the same provider I also define a method that triggers a replication from the local db to the remote node:

```js
  replicateLocalDBToRemote() {
    console.log("Replicating database...");
    this.db.replicate.to(this.remote).then(() => {
      console.log("Celebrate");
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error(error)
    })
  }
```

And here is what the call to `replicateLocalDBToRemote` throws at me

```js
CustomPouchError {__zone_symbol__currentTask: e, result: {…}}
result:
doc_write_failures: 0
docs_read: 0
docs_written: 0
end_time: "2018-11-21T16:23:36.974Z"
errors: []
last_seq: 0
ok: false
start_time: "2018-11-21T16:23:36.874Z"
status: "aborting"
```

and I am afraid I can't call this a self-explanatory message.

Any guess on what might be the root cause of the issue?

**EDIT:** After crawling through the PouchDB repo on github, I found [this entry](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/7450) which might refer to the same problem.

Comment: How many documents were in your local database?

Comment: I would say a hundred or so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by allowing traffic through port 5984 on my remote CouchDB server.

The thing is, sending requests on port 80 (i.e. `GET http://<my_server>.com/mydb`) *does* send back some data so I never bothered to try with port 5984 in the first place because I thought the API was also implemented on port 80...

So at least my issue had nothing to do with PouchDB but I wish the error message was a bit more specific.